# Get users with atleast one post

Tags: users

How can I get all users with atleast one post? I don't think it's possible with `get_users` function.

Comment: This has been answered here for all post types: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31443/how-to-list-users-that-have-written-custom-post-types-and-hide-the-ones-that-hav and works well with a post type of 'post'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
global $wpdb;
$min_posts = 5; // Make sure it's int, it's not escaped in the query
$author_ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT `post_author` FROM
    (SELECT `post_author`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM {$wpdb->posts}
        WHERE `post_status`='publish' GROUP BY `post_author`) AS `stats`
    WHERE `count` >= {$min_posts} ORDER BY `count` DESC;");
// Do what you want to $author_ids from here on...
```

This will return the **User IDs** of the Authors with *5+ published posts* and orders them descending, by post counts.