# Query All users that has post

Tags: posts, query, users, mysql, join-tables

I have this query so far :

```
        $user_args = array(
            'role'    => 'frontend_vendor',
            'orderby' => 'display_name', 
            'order'   => 'ASC',      
            'number'  => $no,
            'offset'  => $offset
        );

        $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $user_args );
```

Now what I want to do is to get all users that has only posts, i have an example query that i want to do. how do i do this with `wp_query()`?

```
SELECT users.id, posts.id 
FROM wp_users 
RIGHT JOIN wp_posts 
ON wp_users.id = wp_posts.user_id 
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'downloads'
AND wp_users.role = 'frontend_vendor' 
ORDER BY display_name 
ASC
LIMT 8
OFFEST 0
```

If the user has no posts, he should not be selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this in your arguments `'query_id' => 'authors_with_posts',`

```
    $user_args = array(
        'role'    => 'frontend_vendor',
        'orderby' => 'display_name', 
        'query_id' => 'authors_with_posts',
        'order'   => 'ASC',      
        'number'  => $no,
        'offset'  => $offset
    );
```

Comment: I just tried this, it works! its so simple!

Answer (score 0):

Here are below some possible options:

[codex link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)

Order & Orderby Parameters we can add post_count otherwise there is no such parameter such as  "posts_per_author" does not exist in wp_query refrence

please include orderby in your query

```
'orderby' => 'post_count'

FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON ( wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id ) LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT post_author, COUNT(*) as post_count
            FROM wp_posts
            WHERE post_type = 'post' AND (post_status = 'publish' OR post_status = 'private')
            GROUP BY post_author
        ) p ON (wp_users.ID = p.post_author)
```

Use count in code according to requirement.

[Get Authors or users](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_authors)

```
<?php $list = wp_list_authors('show_fullname=1&optioncount=1&orderby=post_count&order=DESC&number=3'); ?>
<?php echo"<pre>";   print_r($list); echo"</pre>"; ?>
```

"optioncount" can help in this case.

with direct query please see this post:

[Get users with atleast one post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31722/get-users-with-atleast-one-post)

Thanks!

Comment: hi thanks for a quick reply. but how do i do it with using wordpres wp_query? get all users that has only posts

Comment: i have tried this `wp_list_authors('show_fullname=1&optioncount=1&orderby=post_count&order=DESC&number=3');` but returns null

Comment: I have updated answer, please check and  as well please go thorough codex link mentioned in answer to see parameters.

Comment: i tried this `wp_list_authors` no results, just plain white. is there somethings that i should change on the paramets?

Comment: please make sure that you have users with some added posts, I ca assure you that I am getting list with username and post count in brackets. 

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_authors

Comment: the other guy is much better and simple. thanks for helping me out too :D

Comment: Thats great helped to learn something new !