# Show custom user count in wordpress admin for Published

Tags: custom-post-types

How to show the custom user counts of wordpress posts of multisite user
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ref here: [Showing User's Post Counts by Custom Post Type in the Admin's User List?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3233/showing-users-post-counts-by-custom-post-type-in-the-admins-user-list)

You can write a _manage_users_custom_column() function and can handle it.