# Show a list of user posts in the user admin page

Tags: loop, admin, users, profiles

I have a Wordpress site with multiple authors.

When i see a user profile page i want to have a list (maybe links) of the posts this user is the author of.

How can i do it?

I thought maybe running a standard Wordpress loop with author query but i don't know how to inject that php code in the user admin panel and i don't know if it will work and if that's the right approach...

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3233/showing-users-post-counts-by-custom-post-type-in-the-admins-user-list).

Comment: That's nice, thanks, but i'm looking for a solution that will list them inside the user profile page and not in the users list columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [edit_user_profile](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_user_profile/) (when viewing other user profiles)  and [show_user_profile](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/show_user_profile/) (when viewing your own profile) actions to add information on profile page.

So to have there the list of posts of the selected user you could add to your functions.php:

```
function show_user_posts_on_profile( $user ) {

    $args = array(
        'author' => $user->ID
    );
    $user_posts = get_posts( $args );
    ?>
        <h2>User Posts</h2>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($user_posts as $user_post): ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($user_post->ID); ?>"><?php echo $user_post->post_title; ?></a></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'show_user_posts_on_profile' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'show_user_posts_on_profile' );
```